# RSA algorithm implementation

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, cryptanalysis, decryption

$$m^{ed} \equiv m \bmod n$$
$n =pq$, so by Chinese Remainder Theorem it is equivalent to
$$m^{ed} \equiv m \bmod , m^{ed} \equiv m \bmod q$$
where $n=p\cdot q$

So how did 2 come from 1 by the Chinese remainder theorem?
I know Chinese algorithm but How did $m^{ed} \equiv m \bmod p$ and $q$ come?

Comment: It is a useful way of using the CRT, instead of given two modular equations on $p$ and $q$ to solve on $pq$, now we construct it in $\bmod p$ and $\bmod q$ than solving it. This helps us to have approximately 4x speed up during the calculations.

Comment: Hint: replace $m^{ed}$ by $x$ (and $n$ by $p\,q$ as per their definition in RSA). Do you better recognize the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement)? Picky note: when the question writes "so by Chinese Remainder Theorem" it is forgotten an hypothesis in the CRT; namely, $\gcd(p,q)=1$. That's part of why we use distinct primes in RSA.

Comment: @fgrieu - I had asked the same question in math. I was told that CRT only helps in the unique part - not the actual splitting into 2 congruences - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4000280/use-of-chinese-remainder-theorem-in-proof-of-rsa-correctness

Comment: @kelalaka - I had asked the same question in math. I was told that CRT only helps in the unique part - not the actual splitting into 2 congruences - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4000280/use-of-chinese-remainder-theorem-in-proof-of-rsa-correctness

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for any $n$, $l$, as long as $l | n$, any equivalence $a \equiv b \pmod n$ also holds mod $l$: $a \equiv b \pmod l$ .
To fully see this, we can write

$$
\begin{align*}
    a &\equiv b \pmod n \\
    \Leftrightarrow \\
    a &= b + kn
    \\&=b + ktl \quad(\text{since } l|n\text{, so } n = tl)\\
    \Rightarrow\\
    a &\equiv b \pmod l
\end{align*}
$$

So you could solve $m^e \pmod p \equiv a$ and $m^e \pmod q \equiv b$, then use **CRT** to get $m \pmod n$.

Answer (score 0):

as @fgrieu mentioned above,

- CRT states that : if m and n be two integers such that gcd(m,n)=1 then we have

-$${ f: Z_{mn} -> Z_m \cdot Z_n}$$  defined by ${f(x)=(x mod m, x mod n)}$  is a ring isomorphism

-$${Phi(mn)=Phi(m)Phi(n)}$$